# How do I mount a 50kg (110lb) concrete sculpture on my concrete wall?

Tags: concrete, walls, mounting

Can I use a molly or toggle bolt to mount a 50kg (110lb) concrete sculpture on my concrete wall? The wall is 6inches thick.

Comment: Is the wall *solid* concrete or hollow concrete blocks?

Comment: How high is the wall? Be sure you are not creating a toppling hazard if the sculpture should fall. Falling statuary is an entertaining device in murder mysteries, but in real life would be a tragedy.

Answer (score 3):

Molly or toggle bolts won't work because they need to expand and that can't happen with a concrete wall.  Your best bet is to use lag shields and lag screws like the ones shown below from Lowe's. They come in all different sizes

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Just get some concrete anchors:

[image: anchors]

There are glue-in bolts as well, those things are meant to bolt auto lifts to the floor and all sorts of heavy loads:

[image: adhesive_anchors]

Edit: Oh, and if you can, use a 4-bladed drill. The rounder hole you get makes anchors work much more reliably.